# Как рассылать сообщения, в которых есть фотография, по ID фотографии без её скачивания?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть код, отвечающий за получения текста и фотографии для рассылки. Далее, копируется ID  фотографии и заносится в базу данных. Из базы оно достаётся, и отправляется фотографии по ID этой самой фотографии. Но, при выводи, пишет что такого ID не найдено. В чём может быть проблема?

**Кому нужен код, пишите, я скину**

*Язык - Python, Framework - aiogram3*